# "tail -f" alternate which doesn't scroll the terminal window

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to check a file at continuous intervals for contents which keep changing. "tail -f" doesn't suffice as the file doesn't grow in size.

I could use a simple while loop in bash to the same effect:

```
while [ 1 ]; do cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state ; sleep 10; done
```

It works, although it has the unwanted effect of scrolling my terminal window.

So now I'm wondering, is there a linux/shell command that would display the output of this file without scrolling the terminal?

Comment: I hadn't before receiving that as a suggestion.

Comment: There were a lot of right answers to this. Thanks to gabuzo, SiegeX, Jander and Omnifarious. But the one closest to what I wanted came from Dennis Williamson. Thanks everyone for taking the time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combining several ideas from other answers plus a couple of other tricks, this will output the file without clearing the screen or scrolling (except for the first cycle if the prompt is at the bottom of the screen).

```
up=$(tput cuu1)$(tput el); while true; do (IFS=$'\n'; a=($(</proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state)); echo "${a[*]}"; sleep 1; printf "%.0s$up" ${a[@]}); done
```

It's obviously something you wouldn't type by hand, so you can make it a function that takes the filename, the number of seconds between updates, starting line and number of lines as arguments.

```
watchit () {
    local up=$(tput cuu1)$(tput el) IFS=$'\n' lines
    local start=${3:-0} end
    while true
    do
        lines=($(<"$1"))
        end=${4:-${#lines[@]}}
        echo "${lines[*]:$start:$end}"
        sleep ${2:-1}
        # go up and clear each line
        printf "%.0s$up" "${lines[@]:$start:$end}"
    done
}
```

Run it:

```
watchit /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state .5 0 6
```

The second argument (seconds between updates) defaults to 1. The third argument (starting line) defaults to 0. The fourth argument (number of lines) defaults to the whole file. If you omit the number of lines and the file grows it may cause scrolling to accommodate the new lines.

**Edit:** I added an argument to control the frequency of updates.

Comment: I had originally put a variation with `tput cup 0 0` but I removed it because it required a `clear` and didn't have the ability to start outputting where the cursor currently is.  Your script is exactly what mine aspired to be.  I didn't know about those two `tput` parameters. I'll have to look more into `tput` for future scripts. +1

Comment: P.S. I think you can simply your script just a tad by using `local lines=( $(<"$1") ) IFS=$'\n'` instead of `read` with the here-string

Comment: @SiegeX: Thanks. I took a detour with that `read` for some reason that made sense at the time, then didn't backtrack when it wasn't needed. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I just noticed this is one of the few scripts I've seen that actually made good use of the difference between `${lines[*]}` and `${lines[@]}`.

Comment: Hits the nail on the head. This is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

```
watch -n 10 cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state
```

You can add the `-d` flag if you want it to highlight the differences from one iteration to the next.

Comment: Note that `watch` is installed by default in Debian but not BSD.

Comment: @jleedev: Note that BSD is not linux.

Comment: Both you and gabuzo are right, but I can only mark one as such. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Jagtesh if you only want 6 lines you can use `watch -n 10 head -n 6 /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state`

Comment: @slebetman I know, but I’m on a mission to make people realize that shell scripts are not automatically portable ;)

Comment: @SiegeX Thanks, but it goes fullscreen which defeats the purpose of using -n 6. That's the "curse" of using watch I guess :)

Answer (score 10):

`watch` is your friend. It uses curses so it won't scroll your terminal.

```
Usage: watch [-dhntv] [--differences[=cumulative]] [--help] [--interval=<n>] [--no-title] [--version] <command>
  -d, --differences[=cumulative]        highlight changes between updates
                (cumulative means highlighting is cumulative)
  -h, --help                            print a summary of the options
  -n, --interval=<seconds>              seconds to wait between updates
  -v, --version                         print the version number
  -t, --no-title                        turns off showing the header
```

So taking your example it'll be:

```
watch -n 10 cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state
```

Comment: I didn't give you the -1, someone else did for basically giving a duplicate answer.

Comment: Wow that's harsh we did this at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite, which works in places that don't have `watch`, is this:

```
while true; do clear ; cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state ; sleep 10; done
```

Comment: Interesting take on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The canonical (and easiest, and most flexible) answer is `watch`, as others have said.  But if you want to see just the first line of a file, here's an alternative that neither clears nor scrolls the terminal:

```
while line=`head -n 1 /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state` \
    && printf "%s\r" "$line" \
    && sleep 10
do
    printf "%s\r" "`echo -n "$line" | sed 's/./ /g'`"
done
echo
```

The carriage return is the core concept here.  It tells the cursor to return to the beginning of the current line, like a newline but without moving to the next line.  The `printf` command is used here because (1) it doesn't automatically add a newline, and (2) it translates `\r` into a carriage return.

The first `printf` prints your line.  The second one clears it by overwriting it with spaces, so that you don't see garbage if the next line to be printed is shorter.

Note that if the line printed is longer than the width of your terminal, the terminal will scroll anyway.

Comment: Pretty cool! Now if this could work for 6 lines instead of one, it would be perfect.

Comment: This can be done a bit more simply with: `while line=$(head -n 1 /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state); printf "%-*s\r" $COLUMNS "$line"; sleep 10; done`

Comment: @SiegeX: Nice printf mastery!  I hadn't realized you could do that with shell printf.  Also, I would have expected the cursor to wrap after printing the $COLUMNS'th character, but testing says otherwise.

Comment: Note that $COLUMNS is not available in scripts.  `tput cols` might work, but in the end I hard-coded 80 for my script.